# Flutter update fails

Tags: flutter

```
OS: Windows 10 Pro
```

When I do:

```
flutter channel
```

I get:

```
* beta
  dev
  master
```

If I follow with:

```
flutter upgrade
```

I get:

```
Upgrading Flutter from C:\flutter...
From https://github.com/flutter/flutter
   c799c2fd8..72d86f904  master     -> origin/master
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        .cirrus.yml
        AUTHORS
        CONTRIBUTING.md
        README.md
        analysis_options.yaml
        appveyor.yml
        bin/flutter
        bin/flutter.bat
        bin/internal/engine.version
        bin/internal/goldens.version
        bin/internal/update_dart_sdk.ps1
        dev/automated_tests/flutter_test/exception_handling_expectation.txt
        dev/automated_tests/flutter_test/filtering_test.dart
        dev/automated_tests/flutter_test/test_async_utils_guarded_test.dart
        dev/automated_tests/flutter_test/trivial_test.dart
        dev/automated_tests/flutter_test/trivial_widget_expectation.txt
        dev/automated_tests/pubspec.yaml
        dev/automated_tests/test_smoke_test/crash1_test.dart
        dev/automated_tests/test_smoke_test/crash2_test.dart
        dev/automated_tests/test_smoke_test/fail_test.dart
        dev/automated_tests/test_smoke_test/pass_test.dart
        dev/benchmarks/complex_layout/android/app/build.gradle
        dev/benchmarks/complex_layout/android/build.gradle
        dev/benchmarks/complex_layout/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
        dev/benchmarks/complex_layout/ios/Flutter/AppFrameworkInfo.plist
        dev/benchmarks/complex_layout/ios/Runner.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
        dev/benchmarks/complex_layout/ios/Runner/Info.plist
        dev/benchmarks/complex_layout/lib/main.dart
        dev/benchmarks/complex_layout/pubspec.yaml
        dev/benchmarks/complex_layout/test_driver/scroll_perf_test.dart
        dev/benchmarks/complex_layout/test_driver/semantics_perf_test.dart
        dev/benchmarks/microbenchmarks/android/app/build.gradle
        dev/benchmarks/microbenchmarks/android/build.gradle
        dev/benchmarks/microbenchmarks/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
        dev/benchmarks/microbenchmarks/ios/Flutter/AppFrameworkInfo.plist
        dev/benchmarks/microbenchmarks/ios/Runner.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
        dev/benchmarks/microbenchmarks/ios/Runner/Info.plist
        dev/benchmarks/microbenchmarks/lib/gestures/data/velocity_tracker_data.dart
        dev/benchmarks/microbenchmarks/lib/stocks/animation_bench.dart
        dev/benchmarks/microbenchmarks/lib/stocks/build_bench.dart
        dev/benchmarks/microbenchmarks/lib/stocks/layout_bench.dart
        dev/benchmarks/microbenchmarks/pubspec.yaml
        dev/bots/README.md
        dev/bots/analyze-sample-code.dart
        dev/bots/docs.sh
        dev/bots/prepare_package.dart
        dev/bots/pubspec.yaml
        dev/bots/test.dart
        dev/bots/test/fake_process_manager.dart
        dev/bots/test/fake_process_manager_test.dart
        dev/bots/test/prepare_package_test.dart
        dev/devicelab/README.md
        dev/devicelab/bin/tasks/commands_test.dart
        dev/devicelab/bin/tasks/complex_layout_scroll_perf__memory.dart
        dev/devicelab/bin/tasks/flutter_gallery__back_button_memory.dart
        dev/devicelab/bin/tasks/flutter_gallery__memory_nav.dart
        dev/devicelab/bin/tasks/flutter_gallery_instrumentation_test.dart
        dev/devicelab/bin/tasks/gradle_plugin_test.dart
        dev/devicelab/bin/tasks/hello_world__memory.dart
        dev/devicelab/bin/tasks/routing_test.dart
        dev/devicelab/bin/tasks/service_extensions_test.dart
        dev/devicelab/bin/tasks/technical_debt__cost.dart
        dev/devicelab/lib/framework/adb.dart
        dev/devicelab/lib/framework/framework.dart
        dev/devicelab/lib/framework/ios.dart
        dev/devicelab/lib/framework/runner.dart
        dev/devicelab/lib/framework/utils.dart
        dev/devicelab/lib/tasks/analysis.dart
        dev/devicelab/lib/tasks/gallery.dart
        dev/devicelab/lib/tasks/hot_mode_tests.dart
        dev/devicelab/lib/tasks/integration_tests.dart
        dev/devicelab/lib/tasks/integration_ui.dart
        dev/devicelab/lib/tasks/microbenchmarks.dart
        dev/devicelab/lib/tasks/perf_tests.dart
        dev/devicelab/lib/tasks/plugin_tests.dart
        dev/devicelab/lib/tasks/save_catalog_screenshots.dart
        dev/devicelab/manifest.yaml
        dev/devicelab/pubspec.yaml
        dev/devicelab/test/adb_test.dart
        dev/devicelab/test/manifest_test.dart
        dev/devicelab/test/run_test.dart
        dev/devicelab/test/utils_test.dart
        dev/integration_tests/channels/android/app/build.gradle
        dev/integration_tests/channels/android/build.gradle
        dev/integration_tests/channels/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
        dev/integration_tests/channels/ios/Flutter/AppFrameworkInfo.plist
        dev/integration_tests/channels/ios/Runner.xcodeproj/project.pbxpr
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
        .github/move.yml
        .github/no-response.yml
        dev/automated_tests/test_smoke_test/timeout_fail_test.dart
        dev/automated_tests/test_smoke_test/timeout_pass_test.dart
        dev/benchmarks/complex_layout/test_memory/scroll_perf.dart
        dev/bots/analyze.dart
        dev/bots/cirrus_setup.sh
        dev/bots/codelabs_build_test.sh
        dev/bots/deploy_gallery.sh
        dev/bots/run_command.dart
        dev/bots/test/analyze-sample-code-test-input/known_broken_documentation.dart
        dev/bots/test/analyze-sample-code_test.dart
        dev/bots/test/common.dart
        dev/ci/README.md
        dev/ci/docker_linux/Dockerfile
        dev/ci/docker_linux/README.md
        dev/ci/docker_linux/docker_build.sh
        dev/ci/docker_linux/docker_login.sh
        dev/ci/docker_linux/docker_push.sh
        dev/devicelab/bin/tasks/android_semantics_integration_test.dart
        dev/devicelab/bin/tasks/embedded_android_views_integration_test.dart
        dev/devicelab/bin/tasks/flutter_attach_test.dart
        dev/devicelab/bin/tasks/flutter_test_performance.dart
        dev/devicelab/bin/tasks/hello_world_android__compile.dart
        dev/devicelab/bin/tasks/hello_world_ios__compile.dart
        dev/devicelab/bin/tasks/module_test.dart
        dev/devicelab/bin/tasks/run_release_test.dart
        dev/devicelab/bin/tasks/tiles_scroll_perf__timeline_summary.dart
        dev/devicelab/test/common.dart
        dev/integration_tests/android_host_app/README.md
        dev/integration_tests/android_host_app/app/build.gradle
        dev/integration_tests/android_host_app/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
        dev/integration_tests/android_host_app/app/src/main/java/io/flutter/add2app/MainActivity.java
        dev/integration_tests/android_host_app/build.gradle
        dev/integration_tests/android_host_app/gradle.properties
        dev/integration_tests/android_host_app/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
        dev/integration_tests/android_host_app/settings.gradle
        dev/integration_tests/android_semantics_testing/android/app/build.gradle
        dev/integration_tests/android_semantics_testing/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
        dev/integration_tests/android_semantics_testing/android/app/src/main/java/com/yourcompany/platforminteraction/MainActivity.java
        dev/integration_tests/android_semantics_testing/android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher.png
        dev/integration_tests/android_semantics_testing/android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher.png
        dev/integration_tests/android_semantics_testing/android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher.png
        dev/integration_tests/android_semantics_testing/android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher.png
        dev/integration_tests/android_semantics_testing/android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher.png
        dev/integration_tests/android_semantics_testing/android/build.gradle
        dev/integration_tests/android_semantics_testing/android/gradle.properties
        dev/integration_tests/android_semantics_testing/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
        dev/integration_tests/android_semantics_testing/android/settings.gradle
        dev/integration_tests/android_semantics_testing/lib/android_semantics_testing.dart
        dev/integration_tests/android_semantics_testing/lib/main.dart
        dev/integration_tests/android_semantics_testing/lib/src/common.dart
        dev/integration_tests/android_semantics_testing/lib/src/constants.dart
        dev/integration_tests/android_semantics_testing/lib/src/flutter_test_alternative.dart
        dev/integration_tests/android_semantics_testing/lib/src/matcher.dart
        dev/integration_tests/android_semantics_testing/lib/src/tests/controls_constants.dart
        dev/integration_tests/android_semantics_testing/lib/src/tests/controls_page.dart
        dev/integration_tests/android_semantics_testing/lib/test_constants.dart
        dev/integration_tests/android_semantics_testing/pubspec.yaml
        dev/integration_tests/android_semantics_testing/test/android_semantics_testing_test.dart
        dev/integration_tests/android_semantics_testing/test_driver/main_test.dart
        dev/integration_tests/android_views/.metadata
        dev/integration_tests/android_views/README.md
        dev/integration_tests/android_views/android/app/build.gradle
Updating c7ea3ca37..5ab9e7072
        dev/integration_tests/android_views/android/app/src/main/An
Aborting
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your flutter sdk folder.

Then run the following:

```
git stash
git pull
flutter.bat doctor
```

Comment: No way. You can't have local modifications after a git reset

Comment: Yet, this is what's happening

Comment: Do you have any local change with git status?

Comment: Try a `git stash` + `git pull` + `flutter doctor`

Comment: This is a fresh install, so I did not get a chance to make any changes. In any case, I did do a git stash an a git pull and flutter doctor says that I only have one issue: connect a device

Comment: On windows the install process creates local changes. I don't know why though, but it happens.